# When people say object when they talk about regular expressions, what do they mean (Python)

Tags: python, regex

I'm currently taking a course in Python, and something that my tutor has said, has got me confused. Here is the code that we made.

```
import re
message = "Call me at 415-555-1011 tommorow or at"\
       " 415-555-9999 for my office line"
phoneNumRegX = re.compile(r"\d\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d")
mo = phoneNumRegX.findall(message)
```

He said that we were creating a regular expression object, when we assigned
phoneNumRegX to `re.compile(r"\d\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d")` But what does that mean? I've heard the word object, refer to different things in Python. I was wondering what he meant. Can someone explain what he was talking about?

Comment: ```print(type(re.compile(r"\d\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d")))``` -> ```<class '_sre.SRE_Pattern'>```. ```phoneNumRegX ``` becomes an object of the mentioned class which has a method ```findall```.

Comment: "object' here is a python thing, not a regex thing.

Comment: The result of calling `re.compile` is an object that has methods to do things like search a string, match a string, substitute a string, etc. If you were thinking in object-oriented terms, that's pretty much exactly what you'd expect a regular expression object to do. So people call it that.

Comment: The official Python term is "compiled regular expression", or maybe "compiled regular expression object"; the term in the source code is `SRE_Pattern`. Those are all a bit clumsier to say out loud than "regex object", and they focus on the less interesting part of what the thing is. You don't care that it's compiled, or that it's some SRE thingy, just that it knows how to behave like a regex.

Answer (score 1):

"[regular expression object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re-objects)" is describing an instance of the the [`SRE_Pattern`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/fbb490fd2f38bd817d99c20c05121ad0168a38ee/Modules/_sre.c#L264) class.  This class has methods defined for performing various actions, such as the [`findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.regex.findall) method in your example.

Classes, object and methods are discussed in general the [Classes section of the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html). The introductory paragraph sums it up nicely:

> Classes provide a means of bundling data and functionality together.
>   Creating a new class creates a new type of object, allowing new
>   instances of that type to be made. Each class instance can have
>   attributes attached to it for maintaining its state. Class instances
>   can also have methods (defined by its class) for modifying its state.